# Karate - Robot for WPF Based Desktop application. Unable to identify controls using Inspect.exe as soon as app is launched

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, karate, desktop-application, inspect

I am trying to automate WPF desktop application using Karate Robot DSL.
When I am launching application for the very first time, inspect.exe is unable to identify controls within few tabs unless manually interacted with tabs.

However inspect.exe identifies elements/controls & visual tree shows up the controls & its properties when same tab is opened next time after manually interacting with controls, unlike for the first time launch when it does not load up control & its properties in visual tree.

Is there any settings to trigger inspect.exe so that it can identify elements as soon as app is launched for first time without manually interacting with controls in application.?

Comment: this is impossible to troubleshoot remotely. sounds like some weirdness in your app that you may need to find some creative solution for

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: actually it’s not about code but about identification of ui controls using inspect.exe on wpf based desktop application .. ui controls are not getting identified by inspect which is reason karate script fails even though intended screen is open & visible